# Suggestion for setup of Multiple Store on Magento with a huge catalog

Tags: hosting

We want to start a new website on magento which will have 50+ addon domains setup each running a website and common products across all the websites.

It will contain more than 2 Lakhs of SKUs and  around about 8K categories.

Each website will be at separate domain and will be created on the same admin panel.

We need your suggestion for the below kind of development of magento about 
Server Requirements
Problems may be faced
Space requirements and
What will be the optium solution.

Comment: Today, I learned something new. A lakh is 100,000.